# Tests from other files are run with unittest.main()

Tags: python, unit-testing, spyder, python-unittest

I am using spyder(3.3.4) to run some python(3.7) unit tests.  I have two different scripts that use unittest and unittest.main() open in spyder: test_1.py and test_2.py. Both are saved in the same folder.

If I run test_1.py before ever running test_2.py, I get the expected results; only the tests in test_1.py are run.

If I then run test_2.py, the tests in test_2.py are run, but then the tests in test_1.py are run also. If I restart the Ipython kernel in between running test_1.py and running test_2.py, then only test_2.py runs, as expected.  Weirdest of all, if I close test_1.py after running it, the output of test_1.py is still printed when running test_2.py.

Why is this happening?

I am guessing this has do to do with how the `__name__` variable is saved in the IPython console or how unittest.main() searches for tests?

Here's the code for my two test scripts:
test_1.py:

```py
import unittest

class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        print('test 1')
        pass
    def test_2(self):
        print('test 2')
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and test_2.py:

```py
import unittest

class TestOtherStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        print('this')
        pass
    def test_that(self):
        print('that')
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know `unittest` works, but it seems it tries to run all tests that inherit from it and are present in your session. So you have two options to run them in Spyder: 1. Go to the menu `Run > Configuration per file` and select the option `Remove all variables before execution` so that your namespace is cleared before each run; or 2. In the same menu select `Execute in a dedicated console`, so that files are evaluated on their own consoles.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks for the options to work around the unexpected behavior!